# PyQGIS & Qt - Revisiting the 'dialog window on top' issue

Tags: pyqgis-3

I want to keep a modeless dialog window on top of the main QGIS window. This issue has been discussed before and two solutions have been offered:

1. `self.dlg.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)`. This is
   unsatisfactory because the dialog window stays on top of every application
   window, not just the QGIS one.
2. Give the dialog an owner when it is created, as in `self.dlg = MyCreatorDialog(self.iface.mainWindow())`. This does indeed keep the
   dialog on top of the application's main window, but sets the dialog as modal, so the underlying
   window is inaccessible.

The processing toolbox creates modeless dialog boxes that stay on top of the application window, but not on top of other applications. How does it do it?

Answer (score 1):

When I run the following code in the Python console of QGIS,
the dialog window has the same behavior as the dialog windows in the processing toolbox.

```
dlg = QDialog(iface.mainWindow())
dlg.show()
```

You can achieve this by giving the dialog a parent (here, the main window of QGIS).

**A child dialog always stays on top of its parent window**.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I'm running this from a plugin that I'm writing. Obviously the behaviour is different from the console.

Comment: The result generated by the console is what you're expecting?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Modeless and on top.But doing that from a plugin makes the dialog modal. Maybe I have to reset it to modeless after creating it.

Comment: I'm trying to look in the day or tomorrow.

Comment: Solved it! I was using dlg.open(), but if I use dlg.show() it works perfectly - modeless and on top.

Comment: Perfect! I used open() method in my code too!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109731/discussion-between-vincent-bre-and-tonymj).